# How to use wildcards to get some files and not others if the difference is in the middle of the name?

Tags: bash

I have in the same directory a set of files that start and end the same, but that have something in the middle that makes them different. For example:

```
foo_logis.6.aab
foo_logis.6.log
foo_logis.7.log
foo_simple.6.aab
foo_simple.6.log
foo_simple.7.log
```

What I want to do is very simple, just to use `tail -n 4` in some, but not all of these files.

If I wanted all those that finish on .log (and that is as far of my wildcards knowledge goes) I know I could use: `tail -n 4 *log`. But what I need is to select, and use `tail -n 4`, in only the files that say "simple" in the middle and ".log" at the end.

How can I do this?

Apologies if this is duplicated. I have only basic experience with bash, so I don't really know the right vocabulary for this and may have been unable to look for it properly. If so please point me to the right direction and I can close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use globs anywhere within a filename. So just do e.g.

```
tail -n 4 *simple*.log
```

Comment: +1 for being right in interpreting the requirement :)